# Actualizar registro, se guarda cambios en todos los registros de tabla

Tags: php

Muy buenas, al querer actualizar un registro de una tabla, guarda los datos de ese registro pero cambia tambien todos los registros con los datos del que he querido modificar, entiendo que no recoge bien la id, pero todo funciona y ya no se por donde tirar.
Os paso el código del controlador a ver si veis algún detalle que se me escape. Puede ser que sea problema del formulario?? O si seria problema de la tabla propiamente. De la pagina del formulario recojo la id con un _GET y despues la paso a un input para que se pase con POST.
Gracias,

````
include('../../../app/config.php');

$id_accion = $_POST['id_accion'];
$codigo_acc = $_POST['codigo_acc'];
$fecha_acc = $_POST['fecha_acc'];
$centro_acc = $_POST['centro_acc'];
$responsable_acc = $_POST['responsable_acc'];
$prioridad_acc = $_POST['prioridad_acc'];
$descripcion_acc = $_POST['descripcion_acc'];
$origen_acc = $_POST['origen_acc'];
$detalleorigen_acc = $_POST['detalleorigen_acc'];
$accpropuesta_acc = $_POST['accpropuesta_acc'];
$accrealizada_acc = $_POST['accrealizada_acc'];
$fechaprevista_acc = $_POST['fechaprevista_acc'];
$fecharea_acc = $_POST['fecharea_acc'];
$fechaveri_acc = $_POST['fechaveri_acc'];
$recursos_acc = $_POST['recursos_acc'];
$seguimiento_acc = $_POST['seguimiento_acc'];
$avance_acc = $_POST['avance_acc'];
$estado_acc = $_POST['estado_acc'];



$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ag_acciones
SET codigo_acc=:codigo_acc, 
fecha_acc=:fecha_acc, 
centro_acc=:centro_acc, 
responsable_acc=:responsable_acc, 
prioridad_acc=:prioridad_acc, 
descripcion_acc=:descripcion_acc, 
origen_acc=:origen_acc, 
detalleorigen_acc=:detalleorigen_acc, 
accpropuesta_acc=:accpropuesta_acc, 
accrealizada_acc=:accrealizada_acc, 
fechaprevista_acc=:fechaprevista_acc,
fechaveri_acc=:fechaveri_acc,
fecharea_acc=:fecharea_acc; 
recursos_acc=:recursos_acc, 
seguimiento_acc=:seguimiento_acc,
avance_acc=:avance_acc, 
estado_acc=:estado_acc
WHERE id_accion =: id_accion");


$sentencia->bindParam('codigo_acc', $codigo_acc);    
$sentencia->bindParam('fecha_acc', $fecha_acc);    
$sentencia->bindParam('centro_acc', $centro_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('prioridad_acc', $prioridad_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('origen_acc', $origen_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('detalleorigen_acc', $detalleorigen_acc);    
$sentencia->bindParam('descripcion_acc', $descripcion_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('responsable_acc', $responsable_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('fechaprevista_acc', $fechaprevista_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('fecharea_acc', $fecharea_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('fechaveri_acc', $fechaveri_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('avance_acc', $avance_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('estado_acc', $estado_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('accrealizada_acc', $accrealizada_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('accpropuesta_acc', $accpropuesta_acc);
$sentencia->bindParam('seguimiento_acc', $seguimiento_acc);    
$sentencia->bindParam('recursos_acc', $recursos_acc);


if ($sentencia->execute()) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea editada correctamente";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'success';
header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/accionprl/index.php");
} else {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea NO editada";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'warning';
header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/accionprl/index.php");
}


?> ```
````

Comment: Tenes 2 errores, pero ninguno explica el comportamiento descripto, por el contrario tu código debería fallar. En la consulta, la sintaxis correcta es `WHERE id_accion = :id_accion` y te esta faltando `$sentencia->bindParam('id_accion', $id_accion);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, al fin me di cuenta de que el error estaba en el espacio entre los ":" y id_accion